# Use variables from .wxs file in wix Bootstrapper theme file

Tags: wix

In my bootstrapper Theme.xml I want to reference a path variable from a .wxs file.
In `Bundle.wxs` I reference certain variables using the `$()` syntax.
In my `<BootstrapperApplicationRef>` I use a ThemeFile.

From there I want to use the same variables (for example `var.BundelVersionNumber`). How can I achieve that?

**Bundlex.wxs**

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name="MyApplication $(var.BundelVersionNumber) ($(var.Platform))"
```

I see that I can use some built-in burn variables, for example `[WixBundleName ]`,:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable in your bundle and define the value based on a preprocessor variable.

```
<Variable Name="Platform" Value="$(var.Platform)"/>
```

Then you can use it in your theme.xml (or preferably your localized theme wxl ).

```
[Platform]
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems not to work with image files appearently: `<Variable Name="SideLogo" Value="$(var.Resources_Path)SideLogo.png"/>` won't make `[SideLogo]` usuable in an ImageTag's ImageFile attribute.

Comment: Can't say I've ever tried.  If it's not possible, you might have to have a prebuild step that takes your desired image and copies it to a fixed location that's referenced in the ImageFile attribute.

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason Variable works, but WixVariable appears not to... which was what I had attempted to use.